# Customizing the output of Compass sprites

Tags: sass, compass-sass, css-sprites

I have a top bar menu (that's based on Zurb's Foundation):

This is the SCSS:

```
.top-bar {
  .top-bar-section {
    ul {
      @import "menu-icons/*.png";
      @include all-menu-icons-sprites;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this does what expected, but the problem is that I want to style the `a` element inside each `li` elements (actually, I'd like to apply it to `.top-bar.topbar-section.ul.li.a:before`).

However, since the site is build in WordPress, and so the menu, I can only assign the class to the li element and I have no idea how to make the Compass's spriting work.

I know, I could customize the way the menu is rendered by WordPress using a walker class, but I'd prefer to try finding a solution simply writing the right SCSS, providing that is possible.

Comment: How did you get Foundation and SASS working within your WordPress theme? I'm trying to do the same. Is there a tutorial or resource you used that explains the setup? (Sorry this is tangent to your original question.)

Comment: Actually is not such a big deal, if you start from scratch.
You don't need tutorials, if you know how to build a theme: just create a compass project including foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few sprite helper functions to be aware of when the default output isn't exactly what you want:

- [sprite-url](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-url)
- [sprite-position](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-position)
- [sprite-names](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/620) (undocumented)

Using these you can apply the sprite styles to the children of the `li` elements:

```
.top-bar .top-bar-section ul > li {
    // Generate the sprite map.
    $menu-icons-sprite-map: sprite-map("menu-icons/*.png", $layout: smart);

    // Set the background image.
    > a:before {
        background: sprite-url($menu-icons-sprite-map) 0 0 no-repeat;
    }

    // Set the background position for each sprite.
    $menu-icons-sprite-names: sprite-names($menu-icons-sprite-map);
    @each $name in $menu-icons-sprite-names {
        &.menu-icons-#{$name} > a:before {
           background-position: sprite-position($menu-icons-sprite-map, $name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a bit of troubles to make it work, but eventually I've realized that I had to change the last selector to `&.menu-icons-#{$name} > a:before`. 
Thank you @russ !

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot that the sprite name does not include the folder name. This method allows much more flexibility in the class naming convention :)